# PostgreSQL: Multiple materializations in same query plan?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, execution-plan, performance, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

I have the following query:

Query:

```
SELECT
  a1.id                                                                             id,
  ((SELECT SUM(SFF.pnl)
    FROM positions SFF
      JOIN tag_grid_relations SF ON SFF.stock_id = SF.stock_id
    WHERE SF.tag_value_id = a1.id AND SFF.fund_id = 3 AND SFF.date_id >= 42369)) c0
FROM tag_values a1 LEFT JOIN entities a2 ON a2.id = a1.entity_id
WHERE a1.tag_id = 642 AND a2.archive_on IS NULL;
```

Plan:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.72..4531364.79 rows=157 width=4) (actual time=60.321..8007.218 rows=160 loops=1)
  Filter: (a2.archive_on IS NULL)
  ->  Index Scan using tag_values_tag_id_name_key on tag_values a1  (cost=0.28..29.56 rows=159 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.394 rows=160 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (tag_id = 642)
  ->  Index Scan using entities_pkey on entities a2  (cost=0.43..2.45 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=160)
        Index Cond: (id = a1.entity_id)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=28859.50..28859.51 rows=1 width=7) (actual time=50.026..50.026 rows=1 loops=160)
          ->  Merge Join  (cost=5578.68..28498.68 rows=144330 width=7) (actual time=27.161..49.928 rows=248 loops=160)
                Merge Cond: (sf.stock_id = sff.stock_id)
                ->  Sort  (cost=5578.25..5589.54 rows=4517 width=4) (actual time=0.189..0.195 rows=12 loops=160)
                      Sort Key: sf.stock_id
                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                      ->  Subquery Scan on sf  (cost=5213.70..5304.04 rows=4517 width=4) (actual time=0.163..0.177 rows=12 loops=160)
                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5213.70..5258.87 rows=4517 width=8) (actual time=0.147..0.156 rows=12 loops=160)
"                                  Group Key: stock_fields.tag__2003, stock_fields.stock_id"
                                  ->  Append  (cost=19.13..5191.12 rows=4517 width=8) (actual time=0.040..0.135 rows=12 loops=160)
                                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on stock_fields  (cost=19.13..188.21 rows=167 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=160)
                                              Recheck Cond: ((tag__2003 IS NOT NULL) AND (tag__2003 = a1.id))
                                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on stock_fields_tag__2003_idx  (cost=0.00..19.09 rows=167 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=160)
                                                    Index Cond: ((tag__2003 IS NOT NULL) AND (tag__2003 = a1.id))
                                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on stock_fields stock_fields_1  (cost=583.49..4907.24 rows=4300 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=160)
                                              Recheck Cond: ((tag__2021 IS NOT NULL) AND (tag__2021 = a1.id))
                                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on stock_fields_tag__2021_idx  (cost=0.00..582.41 rows=4300 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=160)
                                                    Index Cond: ((tag__2021 IS NOT NULL) AND (tag__2021 = a1.id))
                                        ->  Index Scan using stock_fields_tag__2048_idx on stock_fields stock_fields_2  (cost=0.41..3.46 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=160)
                                              Index Cond: ((tag__2048 IS NOT NULL) AND (tag__2048 = a1.id))
                                        ->  Index Scan using stock_fields_tag__2034_idx on stock_fields stock_fields_3  (cost=0.41..2.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.098 rows=12 loops=160)
                                              Index Cond: ((tag__2034 IS NOT NULL) AND (tag__2034 = a1.id))
                                        ->  Index Scan using stock_fields_extension1_f102897_idx on stock_fields_extension1  (cost=0.29..44.59 rows=47 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=160)
                                              Index Cond: ((f102897 IS NOT NULL) AND (f102897 = a1.id))
                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.43..20847.44 rows=45820 width=11) (actual time=0.023..51.730 rows=34342 loops=130)
                      ->  Index Scan using positions_fund_id_stock_id_date_id_key on positions sff  (cost=0.43..20732.89 rows=45820 width=11) (actual time=0.021..39.147 rows=34342 loops=130)
                            Index Cond: ((fund_id = 3) AND (date_id >= 42369))
Planning time: 2.149 ms
Execution time: 8007.411 ms
```

The above query takes >8s most of which is spent materializing the same subquery for each row 130 times:

```
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.43..20847.44 rows=45820 width=11) (actual time=0.023..52.512 rows=34342 loops=130)
              ->  Index Scan using positions_fund_id_stock_id_date_id_key on positions sff  (cost=0.43..20732.89 rows=45820 width=11) (actual time=0.021..39.828 rows=34342 loops=130)
                    Index Cond: ((fund_id = 3) AND (date_id >= 42369))
```

Why is PostgreSQL doing this?

Answer (score 0):

PG does this for the merge join - it needs to materialize before merging.

But this isn't what's taking up the time. The Index scan takes 40 out of the 50 ms used to get the positions. 
Given that it returns 34k rows it's not that bad...

You're effectively running 130 aggregative queries each taking 50ms.

It might improve run times to turn the sub select into a join => it will push postgres to scan the table only once for all the reports together.

Comment: > It might improve run times to turn the sub select into a join => it will push postgres to scan the table only once for all the reports together.
------------------
Right, but shouldn't the query optimizer do that for me?

Comment: This transformation is a bit complex- much more than what PG can do...